# Create list of matrices through iterations

Tags: r, list, matrix

I am running iterations a create nxn matrices like this:

```
        X11015      X20004      X20025      X20107      X9086
X11015  1           0.9756098   1           0.804878    0.9512195
X20004  0.625       1           0.921875    0.75        0.828125
X20025  0.3014706   0.4338235   1           0.8382353   0.8014706
X20107  0.1527778   0.2222222   0.5277778   1           0.4814815
X9086   0.3513514   0.4774775   0.981982    0.9369369   1
```

I want to create a list of matrices for each iteration in the loop.

For each iteration the col x row are not constant.

How to do this?

Comment: Can you give some more information? How are your creating one matrix for example?

Comment: please provide some example code, so we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: ade_test <- kerneloverlap(split_ade_1, method = "HR", percent = 95)

matrixStack <- array(data = do.call(cbind, ade_test), dim = c(dim(ade_test[[1]]), length(ade_test)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this did it :-)

```
matrixStack[[i]] <- ade_test <- kerneloverlap(split_ade_1, method = "HR", percent = 95)
```

Comment: you can leave out the `<- ade_test`